# CMake Add and Remove a Macro definition to compile Shared Library/Executable

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a c++ code i need to compile in two ways, a Shared Library and an Executable, In order to do so some of my functions need to be undefined when compiling as a shared library. So i decide to used `#ifdef MACRO` and define `MACRO` in my CMakeLists.txt.

Here is my case :

File `function.cpp` :

```
#include <iostream>

#ifdef _SHARED_LIBRARY_

void printSharedLibrary(void)
{
    std::cout << "Shared Library" << std::endl;
}

#else

void printExecutable(void)
{
    std::cout << "Executable" << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

File `main.cpp` :

```
#ifdef _SHARED_LIBRARY_
    void printSharedLibrary(void);
#else
    void printExecutable(void);
#endif

int main (void)
{
    #ifdef _SHARED_LIBRARY_
        printSharedLibrary();
    #else
        printExecutable();
    #endif
}
```

File `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
project(ProjectTest)

message("_SHARED_LIBRARY_ ADDED BELOW")
add_definitions(-D_SHARED_LIBRARY_)

add_library(TestLibrary SHARED functions.cpp)
add_executable(DefinedExecutable main.cpp) // Only here to be able to test the library
target_link_libraries(DefinedExecutable TestLibrary)

message("_SHARED_LIBRARY_ REMOVED BELOW")
remove_definitions(-D_SHARED_LIBRARY_)

add_executable(UndefinedExecutable main.cpp functions.cpp)
```

Output :

```
$> ./DefinedExecutable
Executable

$> ./UndefinedExecutable
Executable
```

Expected Output :

```
$> ./build/DefinedExecutable
Shared Library

$> ./build/UndefinedExecutable
Executable
```

in order to build it i use : `rm -rf build/ ; mkdir build ; cd build ; cmake .. ; make ; cd ..`

So my question is Is there a way to define `_SHARED_LIBRARY_` for the build of `DefinedExecutable` and then undefine it for the build of `UndefinedExecutable`.
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`target_compile_definitions`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_definitions.html) to specify compile definitions for the given target:

```
target_compile_definitions(TestLibrary PUBLIC _SHARED_LIBRARY_)
```

Then any executable linked against `TestLibrary` will inherit `_SHARED_LIBRARY_` definition.

Comment: To clarify: this works because it adds the definition only to the `TestLibrary` target instead of all targets in the directory.

Comment: Thanks This solves my issue. :) 
Just one thing to add, to anybody who would have this issue, this have to be put **after** the `add_executable(DefinedExecutable main.cpp) ` line

Comment: @Dzious, after `add_library`.